# infinite series with a constant - calculation: $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{c}{x(x+1)(x+3)}=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

In order to continue solving a probability related exercise, I have to extract the value of the constant $c$ from the following: (while $x\in \mathbb{N}$)
$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{c}{x(x+1)(x+3)}=1$$

My first step was to decompose the above to the partial fractions:
$c \cdot \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{((\frac{1}{3x})-(\frac{1}{2(x+1)})+(\frac{1}{6(x+3)}))} = 1$

Then, tried to combine elements of the series to see if I can arrange them in a telescopic way but that failed as well.

Could you please provide a hint or a way to approach this sum calculation?

Comment: prove that your sum is equal to $$\frac{1}{4}c$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I fixed a typing mistake. made the denominator x(x+1)(x+3). What should be the sum, please?

Comment: @KenMizrahi The new sum is $\frac{7c}{36}$.

Comment: yes this is true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{3}{x(x+1)(x+3)}&=\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2(x+2)}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2(x+2)}-\frac{1}{2(x+3)}\right)
\end{align}
$$ then terms *telescope* nicely.

Comment: I fixed a typing mistake in the question. Is there a similar equation for the case with (x+3) instead of (x+2)?

Comment: thank you! If I got you right, I think there should be a plus sign for the last element. Right?